# I need help sending information to my server using Ajax, PHP, and mySQL without using a form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

All of the tutorials I've looked up only show how to everything works using forms. I want to avoid using a form. Right now i have the code for Javascript to map my answering based on what's clicked and make array thats shown in a alert. (in the end i don't want it to be in a alert but im keeping it in there until i know everythings working) but I think i have the ajax sending the info to the server but i'm not sure if its working. Or how to have php take the ajax information and send it to the server. My server is also connected fine. I'm posting all of my current code. Any help is appreciated. Even if you just send me a link or point me in the right direction that would be great.

I think my biggest question is how to take the array generated in Javascript then call in in Ajax, then Php. since i already made the array what do i call in the Ajax. then how to treat it with a PDO

[current jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tdring/jba58xbb/)

```
<?php
    include_once('database.php');
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $choices = $_POST['answers'];
    if(mysql_query("INSERT INTO answers VALUES('$name', '$choices')"))
     echo "Successfully Inserted";
    else
    echo "Insertion Failed";?>
```

jQuery

```
 $(document).ready(function() {


   $(function() {
     //catch this values, because you will use these for more than one time
     var answers = [];

     function getAnswers() {
         answers = []; //empty old answers so you can update it
         $.map($('.on'), function(item) {
           answers.push($(item).data('value'));
         });
       }
       //init the answers in case you use it before click
     getAnswers();


     $(document).on('click', 'img', function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       $(this).toggleClass('on');

       //trigger the state change when you click on an image
       $(document).trigger('state-change');
     });

     //get answers when event was triggered
     $(document).on('state-change', function(e) {
       getAnswers();
     });

     $('#btn-show').click(function() {
       alert(answers.join(',') || 'nothing was selected');
     });

   });
 });
```

CSS

```
#seasoning {
  margin: 8px;
  font-size: 16px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
/* this shows the user which item has been selecting along with making a searchable class for the program */

.on {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

HTML

```
<html>

<head>
  <LINK REL=StyleSheet HREF="code.css" TYPE="text/css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <form>
    Name:
    <input type="text" name="name">
  </form>
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/7HyU4yh.jpg" id="seasoning" data-value="0">
  <br>
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/OEHCjCK.jpg" id="seasoning" data-value="1">
  <br>

  <button id="btn-show">Submit</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I don't see any ajax requests in your javascript.

Comment: i think have might have mistaken my php code for ajax on accident and forgotten about it. ill work on that part now

Comment: Make sure you pass the information about which element was clicked from your `click` function to the other functions.

Comment: You don't need a form if you use ajax. But having a form is necessary for server side validation.

Comment: [Here is an example of what happens when you continue to use `mysql_*` functions.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26299564/php-version-upgraded-cannot-use-few-functions) Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://us1.php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://us1.php.net/mysqli). [This article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide.

Comment: @user1906399 would you suggest adding radial buttons and just using a form instead?

Comment: @jayBlanchard i looked that up and ill try to implement PDO into my code.

Comment: A form is not needed for server-side validation either...

Comment: a form is needed for php validation, which is server side validation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely:

```
//    $(document).on("eventOfYourChoice", function() {
// you probably actually want to do:
 $('#btn-show').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/path/to/script.php",
        data: { 
            "name" : $('input[name="name"]').val(),
            "answers" : answers
        },
        success: function(response){
            alert(response);
    }
    }); 

});
```

the `response` variable contains whatever your PHP echoes out --

However, there are a couple of things to note in the code you posted -

1). Filter & Validate your input:

```
if (is_string($_POST['name']){

$name = filter_var($_POST['name'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

} else { die("That input is not valid"); }
```

2). Use mysqli_* functions or PDO --- or, you could use an ORM/DBA like [idiorm](https://github.com/j4mie/idiorm)

3). In your JS - `$(document).ready(function(){...` and `$(function()` are the same thing. you only really need one.

4). You almost ALWAYS want to include jQuery before any other scripts-- but you don't *have* to unless your `javascript.js` contains jQuery code (i.e. anything that begins

---edit----

I missed the "answer" value, earlier - but, since you have images, I'm assuming you want to do something along these lines:

Hope this helps -!

Comment: i think your forgot to put something after "along these lines". i have the answers variable as an array currently

Comment: Actually, I forgot to take that out... so long as that array is getting populated properly, then this should be a suitable answer. Let me know if I need to elaborate , elsewhere !

Comment: hello again. I did what you suggest but google is giving me an error "Uncaught ReferenceError: answers is not defined " in the "answers" : answers part of ajax

Comment: Then your `answers` array isn't getting defined, before the ajax call is made --- what was the answers array supposed to contain?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use ajax without using a form . suppose your `index.php` is as below

```
  <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <input type="text" id="name">
        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="submit">

      <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">

       $(document).ready(function(){

        var name = $('#name').val();

        $('#submit').click(function(){

         $.post('validate.php', {name:name}, function(data){

           alert(data);
        });

       });  

      });

    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Now create the `validate.php` file, code there will be something like

```
if(isset($_POST['name'])){
  //do things with database

   if(//success){

     echo "success";
   }else{
     echo "failure";
   }

}
```

The output of this page will be alerted in index.php