# Table will not update, however showing successful

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am new to MYSQL

When i try to update a database, the result is showing successful, but the item is not showing. Please can someone help. I have tried carrying it over, by turning the post into a session variable, but made no difference.

update_ac.php

```
                $name = $_POST['name'];
            $lastname = $_POST['review'];

            // Connect to server and select database.
            mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
            mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

            // update data in mysql database
            $sql="UPDATE reviews SET name='$name', review='$lastname' WHERE id='$id'";
            $result=mysql_query($sql);

            // if successfully updated.
            if($result){
            echo "Successful";
            echo "<BR>";
            echo "<a href='list_reviews.php'>View result</a>";
            }

            else {
            echo "ERROR";
            echo "Welcome ". $_POST['name']. "<br />";
            echo $lastname; 
            }

            ?>
```

update.php

```
                // Connect to server and select database.
            mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
            mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

            // get value of id that sent from address bar
            $id=$_GET['id'];

            // Retrieve data from database
            $sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE id='$id'";
            $result=mysql_query($sql);

            $rows=mysql_fetch_array($result);
        ?>

        <?php include "includes/header.php"; ?>
                <div id="bodywrap">
                    <div id="leftcol">
                    <h1>Update the form</h1>

        <form name="form1" method="post" action="update_ac.php">
        <label>Name</label>
        <input name="name" type="text" id="name" value="<? echo $rows['name']; ?>">
        <br />
        <label>Review</label>
        <input name="lastname" type="text" id="lastname" value="<? echo $rows['review']; ?>" size="15">
        <br />
        <input name="id" type="hidden" id="id" value="<? echo $rows['id']; ?>">
        <br />
        <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
        </form>

        <?php
        // close connection
        mysql_close();
        ?>
```

Comment: Where is $tbl_name SET?

Comment: [Here is an example of what happens when you continue to use `mysql_*` functions.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26299564/php-version-upgraded-cannot-use-few-functions) Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://us1.php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://us1.php.net/mysqli). [This article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide.

Comment: +1 to Jay. And try posting what $id have setted please.

Comment: $tbl_name has been set, its with the connections, which i left out for security purposes. it will be reviews.

Answer (score 1):

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$lastname = $_POST['review'];
```

Did you notice you used $id and not $_POST['id'] or $_REQUEST['id'] or $_GET['id']? Missing this:

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
```

The SQL worked because it DID update on every id='' it found, so it was not an error.

Also, as others pointed out, use mysqli, mysql extension is dangerous and probably will be deprecated soon

Comment: The old mysql extension has already been deprecated, as of PHP 5.5.0. New projects should use mysqli or PDO (I prefer PDO). See http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php

Comment: I don't use mysql extension for about 5 years so I don't actually follow if it is deprecated or not =p Good to know though, I still support it on legacy servers, now I can just drop that thing

Comment: Yeah, it's going to be hard to get the deprecated extension out of legacy applications. It's not worth re-writing millions of lines of code for that reason alone. But we should switch to the newer extensions for new projects.