# Disable a specific link permanently when clicking another link-PHP

Tags: php

```
 $newcomments= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comments,items WHERE comments.ino=items.ino AND comments.ino='$ino' AND uid='$uname'") or die ("cant get new comments");
      $row3=mysql_fetch_array($newcomments);
      $new_com_no=$row3['com_no'];

 echo" <form name='postform' class='form-horizontal' role='form' method='post' action='member.php?uname=$uname&ino=$ino&cid=$cid&commit=$commit&role=$role&title=$title&op_type=PostComment' align='right'>
      <h4 align='center'><font face='Trebuchet MS'>Comment Details</font></h4>
      <table class='table table-hover borderless' style='width:600px;' align='center'>
      <tr>
        <th align='left'>Comment</th>
        <th align='left'>Actions</th>
      </tr>";

  while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($comments))
  {
     $comment=$row['comment'];
     $com_no=$row['com_no'];
     $uid=$row['uid'];
     $decision=$row['decision'];
 $ino=$row2['ino'];
     $cid=$row2['cid'];
     $title=$row2['title'];

     echo "<tr><td> ";
     echo $comment;
     echo"</td><td>";
```

when user click 'post comment' link in front of a comment,that respective comment is stored in a database table.
In here, it checks whether comment number is already in the database table.
My problem is when i click 'post comment' link, all the edit links are disabled. 
What i want is to disable only the specific 'edit' link, which the comment is in the database.

```
     if($com_no=$new_com_no)
   {
        $com_no=$row['com_no'];
        echo"<a class='btn btn-small btn-info'  disabled>Edit</a>";
    }
   else{
      $com_no=$row['com_no'];
     echo"<a href='member.php?uname=$uname&ino=$ino&cid=$cid&com_no=$com_no&comment=$comment&op_type=EditComment' class='btn btn-small btn-info'>Edit</a>";
   }


     $com_no=$row['com_no'];

     echo"</td>
     <td><a href='member.php?uname=$uname&com_no=$com_no&ino=$ino&cid=$cid&title=$title&comment=$comment&op_type=PostComment' class='btn btn-small btn-warning'>Post Comment</a>   
     </td></tr>";

   }

    echo"<tr><td>";

    echo"<font face='Exo' color='#808080'>Please Click 'Post Comment' to Submit Your Comments</font>";

   echo"<a class='btn btn-success btn-small' href='member.php?uname=$uname&com_no=$com_no&ino=$ino&cid=$cid&title=$title&op_type=GetApproval'>Approval</a>

   <a class='btn btn-primary btn-small' href='member.php?uname=$uname&com_no=$com_no&ino=$ino&cid=$cid&title=$title&op_type=GetComment'>Comment</a>

   <input class='btn btn-default btn-small' type='button' value='Cancel' onClick='history.back()'>
   </td></tr>";

echo"</table></form>";
```

Comment: Thanks.But does it effect to my problem even if i changed??

Comment: Probably not, but it definitely will become a problem. [Here is an example of what happens when you continue to use `mysql_*` functions.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26299564/php-version-upgraded-cannot-use-few-functions)

Comment: well, okay. i'll change it.Thank you very much.

Comment: use js\jquery u can implement a client side function that get an array of values\id and disable that links if matched

Comment: VeNoMiS does that disable the correspondng link?? can you show an example if possible ?? thanks :)

Comment: Fred -ii I have used '==' instead of '=' and when i clicked post comment link, it disable the corresponding edit link only once. (which didn't worked earlier). but when i click post comment link to post another comment, then it do not disable the edit link..  any idea??

Comment: Fred-ii... the edit link is not disabling when more than one comments are posted. think something have to be done with the condition i used (if). any idea of solving this??

Comment: Come to teamviewer to check problem practically.

Comment: RajaRassani- How to join with it???