# Issues following mySQL upgrade

Tags: php, mysql

I currently have a website which is hosted on Joomla 2.5 we were having consistent database crashed which meant i had to constantly repair databases. Reluctantly I upgraded to mySQL 5.6 which has caused a problem with part of my website now.

You'll have to bear with me as i am novice...

the error i am facing is:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_real_escape_string() in
 /home/seafoods/public_html/landings/images-4/administrator/components/com_ose_cpu/oseregistry/database/osedbMySQL.php on line 182
```

I have done some research and i believe that the function mysql_real_escape_string() is depreciated. I have seen suggestion to convert to mysqli but basically i am out of my depth and i am looking for some advice.

Thanks guys
Have a nice day

Comment: [Here is an example of what happens when you continue to use `mysql_*` functions.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26299564/php-version-upgraded-cannot-use-few-functions) Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://us1.php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://us1.php.net/mysqli). [This article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide.

Comment: The `mysql_` functions are indeed deprecated, but for this warning to appear, you would have to update your PHP not the MySQL server. Anyhow, I suggest migrating to MySQLi or PDO and use parametrized queries instead of manual escaping of user input.

Answer (score 1):

it is deprecated, but you have no control over Joomla's codebase, so it's pointless to advise changing it.

I guess your php-mysql extension got uninstalled when you upgraded mysql. Please try

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mysql
```

Or edit accordingly to your package manager. Restart php-fpm or apache afterwards.

**Edit**: to see what php extensions you are running, create a file in your web root folder, called info.php, whose only contents should be

```
<?php
phpinfo();
```

Load the file in your browser and look for mentions to mysql.

Comment: deprecated warning? it says "call to undefined function"

Comment: My bad. Just saw his later assumption about the deprecation.

Comment: Hi amenadiel. Like i said im novice, where do i run that command?

Comment: in the command line. Same where you did the mysql upgrade to 5.6

Comment: Hi, I upgraded via cpanel

Comment: do you have a way to see phpinfo from cpanel? Thay way you could check if mysql extension is loaded.

Comment: if you're using cpanel, most probably you don't have privileges to install anything, so if you don't have php-mysql extension you're pretty much screwed.  I'll edit my post with instructions to see phpinfo